# How to avoid duplications return distinct nodes and the relation ship using neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to return for a given node-id related nodes and their relationships props

For example:
`->` defines a bi direction relationship with property timestamp

```
1234->777
777->1234
1234->999
999->1234
1234->888
888->1234
```

1234,777,888,999 are node-ids

When I execute this:

```
    final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("start a = node(1234) match (a)-[k:nearby*]->(b) where a<>b return DISTINCT b, k");        
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
         Map result = (Map<String, Object>) rs.getObject("b");     
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    logger.error("Error returning userId=" + userIdInput, e);
}
return null;
```

}

I get:

```
{userId=777}
{userId=999}
{userId=888}
{userId=888}
{userId=999}
{userId=999}
{userId=777}
{userId=888}
{userId=888}
{userId=777}
{userId=888}
{userId=777}
{userId=999}
{userId=999}
{userId=777}
```

1. How I do get distinct results only (777,888,999)
2. How to retrieve the relationship props of 1234 to the dest node? I expect to get the **timestamp** prop which defined on each relationship

Thank you,
ray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what language you're using so I'll focus on the Cypher.  Firstly I would replace the `START` query with a `MATCH` with a `WHERE` on `ID(a)`:

```
MATCH (a)-[k:nearby*]->(b)
WHERE ID(a) = 1234 AND a<>b
RETURN DISTINCT b, k
```

Secondly I'm pretty sure you don't need the `a<>b` because Cypher paths won't loop back on the same nodes:

```
MATCH (a)-[k:nearby*]->(b)
WHERE ID(a) = 1234
RETURN DISTINCT b, k
```

Lastly, and to your question, I suspect the reason that you're getting duplicates is because you have multiple relationships.  If so you can return the result node and an array of the relationships like so:

```
MATCH (a)-[k:nearby*]->(b)
WHERE ID(a) = 1234
RETURN collect(b), k
```

That should return you node/relationship objects (with properties on both).  Depending on your language/library you might get Maps or you might get objects wrapping the data

If your library doesn't return the start/end nodes for relationships for you, you can do something like this:

```
MATCH (a)-[k:nearby*]->(b)
WHERE ID(a) = 1234
RETURN collect({rel: b, startnode: startnode(b), endnode: endnode(b)}), k
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I edited my question. I forgot something important. the relations are both ways please check it out

Comment: it's java with JDBC :)

Comment: Brian, Could you also show me how can I get the outgoing relations properties from the 1234 node to all others ? I cant nail this down. to get something like 1234->777 + the timestamp that was set on the relationship

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand.  If you return the relationship or an Array of relationships (like I show above) you should get all of the properties of that relationship (probably as a `Map`.  It depends on your driver).  If you just want one property you could do `RETURN collect(b.property_name)`, though.

Comment: Michael,  I did get an array of relationships props but how ill know which relation value is belong to node pairs?

Comment: Again, depending on your library ;)  Relationship data when returned from Neo4j, should have a concept of `start` and `end` nodes.  If you don't have those you could return them explicitly like `RETURN collect({rel: b, startnode: startnode(b), endnode: endnode(b)}), k`

Comment: I am using neo4j-jdbc. so I got start/end and also match. Could you please edit your answer so I could connect the dots together?  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You get non distinct results, because you return both `b` and `k`

If you only want to get distinct `b`'s use:

```
MATCH (a)-[k:nearby*]->(b)
WHERE ID(a) = 1234 AND a<>b
RETURN DISTINCT b
```

You should also use parameters!

```
MATCH (a)-[k:nearby*]->(b)
WHERE ID(a) = {1} AND a<>b
RETURN DISTINCT b


ps.setInt(1,1234);
```

Comment: I want to get distinct's b's  nodes and their outgoing relationships props as I demonstrated. the way you showing it I will only get the nodes without the props on the relationship connectors(nearby's)