# handling ORDER BY and unique attributes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, distinct

I am trying to use the ORDER BY clause and DISTINCT which is not handling well so far

```
MATCH (p:Project {projectName: "Digital Lab"})
MATCH (p)<-[:PART_OF]-(d)
RETURN d.date, d.prop1, d.prop2, d.prop3 ORDER BY d.date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Ofcourse this gives me a order by date table. BUT I have 3 unique property values for d.prop1 which repeats

```
d.date    d.prop1    d.prop2    d.prop3
123       a          123123     c54655
111       a          454565     b75655
110       b          456464     d46546
103       c          454211     e45645
100       c          465562     f45646
```

Now i would like to get a table which has the newest data according to date and unique prop1 value, which means

```
d.date    d.prop1    d.prop2    d.prop3
123       a          123123     c54655
110       b          456464     d46546
103       c          454211     e45645
```

I used this after, but as usual spent many hours with no progess...

```
MATCH (p:Project {projectName: "Digital Lab"})
MATCH (p)<-[:PART_OF]-(d) WITH DISTINCT d.prop1 AS pro
RETURN d.date, pro, d.prop2, d.prop3 ORDER BY d.date DESC LIMIT 10
```

I would appreciate help and really looking forward to a solution from this helpful community :)

Comment: You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677104/how-to-avoid-duplications-return-distinct-nodes-and-the-relation-ship-using-neo4

Or make query like this:
MATCH (p:Project {projectName: "Digital Lab"})
MATCH (p)<-[:PART_OF]-(d) WITH DISTINCT d.prop1 AS pro
RETURN d.date, DISTINCT pro, d.prop2, d.prop3 ORDER BY d.date DESC LIMIT 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a sample data for test purposes:

```
CREATE (p:Project {projectName : "Digital Lab"})
CREATE (d1 {date: 123, prop1: 'a', prop2: 123123, prop3 : 'c54655'})
CREATE (d2 {date: 111, prop1: 'a', prop2: 454565, prop3 : 'b75655'})
CREATE (d3 {date: 110, prop1: 'b', prop2: 456464, prop3 : 'd46546'})
CREATE (d4 {date: 103, prop1: 'c', prop2: 454211, prop3 : 'e45645'})
CREATE (d5 {date: 100, prop1: 'c', prop2: 465562, prop3 : 'f45646'})
CREATE (p)<-[:PART_OF]-(d1)
CREATE (p)<-[:PART_OF]-(d2)
CREATE (p)<-[:PART_OF]-(d3)
CREATE (p)<-[:PART_OF]-(d4)
CREATE (p)<-[:PART_OF]-(d5)
```

Tris query should work:

```
MATCH (p:Project {projectName: "Digital Lab"})<-[:PART_OF]-(d)
WITH d as d ORDER BY d.prop1, d.date DESC
WITH d.prop1 as prop1, collect(d) as items
ORDER BY prop1
RETURN items[0]
```

The output:

```
╒════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"items[0]"                                              │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"prop2":123123,"date":123,"prop1":"a","prop3":"c54655"}│
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"prop2":456464,"date":110,"prop1":"b","prop3":"d46546"}│
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"prop2":454211,"date":103,"prop1":"c","prop3":"e45645"}│
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Sweet lord, you helped me twice with Neo4j! Thanks again Bruno!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query :

```
MATCH (p)<-[:PART_OF]-(d) 
WITH d.prop1 AS pro,d.date AS date, d
ORDER BY pro, date DESC
WITH collect(d) AS items
WITH items[0] AS d
RETURN d.date, d.prop1, d.prop2, d.prop3 ORDER BY d.date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Cheers